# Howto define icon for C# fcm push notification

Tags: c#, audio, firebase-cloud-messaging, icons

I send a notification like this

```
FirebaseApp.Create(new AppOptions()
            {
                Credential = GoogleCredential.FromFile("private_key.json")
            });

            // This registration token comes from the client FCM SDKs.
            var registrationToken = "TOKEN_HERE";

            // See documentation on defining a message payload.

            var message = new Message()
            {
                Data = new Dictionary<string, string>()
    {
        { "myData", "1337" },
    },
              
           Token = registrationToken,
                //Topic = "all",
                Notification = new Notification()
                {
                    Title = "Test from code",
                    Body = "Here is your test!"
                }
            };

            // Send a message to the device corresponding to the provided
            // registration token.
            string response = FirebaseMessaging.DefaultInstance.SendAsync(message).Result;
            // Response is a message ID string.
            Console.WriteLine("Successfully sent message: " + response);
```

I want to define the icon associated to the notification and the sound for ios and android ?
Is it in this code that i must specify these information or in the application and how ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The icon is a property called ImageUrl when you initialize the Notification object:

> ```
>            Notification = new Notification()
>            {
>                Title = "Test from code",
>                Body = "Here is your test!",
>                //Add this
>                ImageUrl = "somePath.jpg"
>            }
>        };
> ```

And for sound, you need to initialize another object called Apns, like this:

```
Apns = new ApnsConfig()
{
    Aps = new Aps()
    {
        //Change this for the sound you would like
        Sound = "default"
    }
}
```

Entire solution based in the code you provided:

```
FirebaseApp.Create(new AppOptions()
            {
                Credential = GoogleCredential.FromFile("private_key.json")
            });

            // This registration token comes from the client FCM SDKs.
            var registrationToken = "TOKEN_HERE";

            // See documentation on defining a message payload.

            var message = new Message()
            {
                Data = new Dictionary<string, string>()
    {
        { "myData", "1337" },
    },
              
           Token = registrationToken,
                //Topic = "all",
                Notification = new Notification()
                {
                    Title = "Test from code",
                    Body = "Here is your test!"
                    //Add this
                    ImageUrl = "somePath.jpg"
                },
                Apns = new ApnsConfig()
                {
                    Aps = new Aps()
                    {
                        //Change this for the sound you would like
                        Sound = "default"
                    }
                }
            };

            // Send a message to the device corresponding to the provided
            // registration token.
            string response = FirebaseMessaging.DefaultInstance.SendAsync(message).Result;
            // Response is a message ID string.
            Console.WriteLine("Successfully sent message: " + response);
```